# ruby sort_by multiple fields

Tags: ruby, sorting

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3p392.

```
Item = Struct.new( :name, :dir, :sort_dir )

entries = ftp.list()
entries.map!{|e| Net::FTP::List.parse(e) }.map!{|e| Item.new( e.basename, e.dir?, (e.dir? ? 0 : 1) ) }

render json: entries.sort_by{ |e| [ e.sort_dir, e.name ]}
```

For some reason, I am not getting the results back as expected.

I do get all folders first followed by all files, however, the name sorting is failing.

As an example, I get these for my folders:

1. content
2. images
3. bin

For files:

1. global.asax
2. web.config
3. favicon.ico

It groups the dir/file portion correct, but the names are sorted incorrectly.

The output to the console looks like this after sorting:

```
#<struct FtpController::Item name="Content", dir=true, sort_dir=0>
#<struct FtpController::Item name="Images", dir=true, sort_dir=0>
#<struct FtpController::Item name="Scripts", dir=true, sort_dir=0>
#<struct FtpController::Item name="Views", dir=true, sort_dir=0>
#<struct FtpController::Item name="bin", dir=true, sort_dir=0>
#<struct FtpController::Item name="Global.asax", dir=false, sort_dir=1>
#<struct FtpController::Item name="Web.config", dir=false, sort_dir=1>
#<struct FtpController::Item name="favicon.ico", dir=false, sort_dir=1>
#<struct FtpController::Item name="packages.config", dir=false, sort_dir=1>
#<struct FtpController::Item name="robots.txt", dir=false, sort_dir=1>
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Your sorting works correctly in MRI Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.3, and 2.0.0:

```
Item = Struct.new(:name, :dir, :sort_dir)

entries = [Item.new('favicon.ico', false, 1), Item.new('bin', true, 0),
           Item.new('web.config', false, 1), Item.new('images', true, 0),
           Item.new('global.asax', false, 1), Item.new('content', true, 0)]

entries.sort_by{|e| [e.sort_dir, e.name]}
# => [#<struct Item name="bin", dir=true, sort_dir=0>,
#     #<struct Item name="content", dir=true, sort_dir=0>,
#     #<struct Item name="images", dir=true, sort_dir=0>,
#     #<struct Item name="favicon.ico", dir=false, sort_dir=1>,
#     #<struct Item name="global.asax", dir=false, sort_dir=1>,
#     #<struct Item name="web.config", dir=false, sort_dir=1>]
```

Have you tried outputting the result of your `sort_by` to a console?  I'm not familiar with the `render json:` portion of your code, but perhaps that's where things are going wrong.  My best guess is that somehow in the conversion to JSON (if that's what it does) the sorting  is getting messed up.

My other idea is that perhaps you expect `sort_by` to modify `entries`; it does not.  If you want `entries` itself to be sorted after the call, use `sort_by!` (note the `!` at the end of the method name).

**Update:** It looks like the issue is that you want a case-insensitive search.  Simply adding `upcase` should do the trick:

```
entries.sort_by{|e| [e.sort_dir, e.name.upcase]}
```

Comment: I included the console output into original question. Also, I am not expecting entries itself to be sorted. I'm expecting it to return a sorted list back to the render method. However, the json that I get back and the console output matches.

Comment: @Mike It looks like the issue is that you want a case in-sensitive sort, then?  Because your output is sorted, just upper-case first.

Comment: can you add your comment as an answer so I can vote it as being correct. I added a downcase to name and it's working as expected. Thanks!

Comment: how would this for *three conditions* instead of two, and different order for different conditions is required in sorting?

Eg. I have database enteries with columns date, timestamp, status. I was trying to sort the results by date (descending order), then status (ascending) and then time (ascending order) Date is not a actual column, i'm retrieving date using timestamp.to_date
     
Trying this
'code'@results = @results.sort_by { |x| [-x.timestamp.to_date, x.status, x.timestamp]} 
to get desired order is failing, because x.timestamp.to_date is not integer.