# Sorting 2 colums in a table in Ruby on Rails using haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml

I am kind of new at rails, currently using version 3.23 and I am trying to enable 'sort' on two columns in my table. I managed to create the links on these column headers and actually got one column working/sorting!But couldnt achieve the same result when I modified my code in the movie controller rb, my code can only work for one column! is:

```
def index
  @movies = Movie.all.sort_by { |movie| movie.title } 
end
```

Works perfectly, but when I combine another parameter i.e. release date I get an error!

```
def index
  @movies = Movie.all.sort_by { |movie| movie.title } then { |release date| release.date}
end
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue? I have researched it on google but I've gotten nothing conclusive!. Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: `[movie.title, movie.release.date]` or whatever `release` actually is. You're not "combining" anything, you're using random syntactic expressions instead of searching the web for sort_by multiple fields, which turns up things like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076372/ruby-sort-by-multiple-fields. Arguably you'd be better served by sorting on the DB side instead of getting all the movies and sorting in Ruby, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have to sort on `title` and `release_date` fields in `movies` table.

You can perform the sorting at database level itself as below:

### In Rails 4.x:

Below will sort all the movie records with title and release_date in ascending order(as default).

```
def index
  @movies = Movie.order(:title, :release_date)
end
```

If you want to change the order, you can specify as `asc` or `desc` as:

```
def index
  @movies = Movie.order(title: :asc, release_date: :desc)
end
```

### In Rails 3.x:

```
def index
  @movies = Movie.all(:order => "title ASC, release_date ASC")
end
```

If you want to change the order, you can specify as `DESC` in the above case.

Comment: @user3435842 Glad to help :). Please accept the answer when you get a chance. Also, was I correct on `release_date` as a field and not `release.date`?

Comment: Kirti you were indeed correct on release_date,though I would like my columns to sort both directions :asc and :desc upon clicking on column! I am trying to figure out a way of making them more dynamic

Comment: Glad to help :). I suppose you are looking for tablesorter kinda thing. In that case Javascript would come in picture. Take a look at `jquery-tablesorter ` gem. It might help. Also, I would recommend you to try to resolve the problem on your own first. When you get stuck you could always post a question, so some expert can guide you in proper direction.

Comment: Kirti thank you so much for your assistance.. I think i figured it out.

Comment: Thats great!! Good job :)

Comment: Hi Kirti, I hate to bother you again,but I am trying to highlight the movie title head upon sorting! I tried by inserting the code below in my index.html.haml; %th{:class => ('title' == @sortby)?'hilite':""}= link_to 'Movie Title', :id => 'title_header', :sort => "Movie Title" and also added a code to appl.css file; table#movies th.hilite {
  background-color: yellow; Made no changes in the controller.rb, Movie title didnt highlight upon sorting! Is there something I am missing? maybe I need to update code in the controller? Any assistance will be most appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You can order your listing by this

```
def index
    @movies = Movie.order(title: :asc, release_data: :desc)
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kirti Thorat and Mayank, those methods worked perfectly!! I truly appreciate your time in assisting me, pity I couldn’t figure it out on my own.